# Passing a GET value in route

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have this following Controllers on my file

```
class MyController1 extends BaseController{

    public function notify($id,$message){
        //Sending a push notification
        //Google Cloud Messaging Here
        //****//
    }
}
```

How do i write the route to pass a value to `id` and `message` using GET?

```
Route::get("/sendMessage" , MyController1@notify);
```

the url should be something like

```
https://mysite.com/sendMessage?id=1&message=Hello
```

Also I need to call the `notify` method from other controllers like this. .

```
class MyController2 extends BaseController{

    public function something(){  
         $con = new MyController2();
         $con->notify($id,$message);

    }
}
```

What should I put to the notify the model?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you need to create GET parameters in your URL:

```
Route::get('sendMessage/{id}/{msg}'
```

More information here: 
http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Laravel URL's work slightly differently to how you want it.

In Laravel as standard your URL for the above example will be

```
https://mysite.com/sendMessage/1/Hello
```

and your route would be

```
Route::get("/sendMessage/{id}/{message}" , MyController1@notify);
```

the text in the braces {} will be the name of the parameter passed to the controller function

eg. https://mysite.com/sendMessage/1/Hello would call MyController->notify(1,'Hello');